# WebAii ArtOfTest need help finding a dynamically added element (label)

Tags: jquery, testing, automation, webautomation, webaii

Good Morning All,

I'm doing some web automation testing using WebAii ArtOfTest.  It's similar to Watin. Anyways, I'm trying to find a label element by its `for` attribute.  Using the jQuery validation plug in, a label element is added dynamically to store the error message for a textbox. No `id` is given to the element, just a class and the `for` attribute.  I'm using WebAii to search by attribute `for=textBoxMileage`.  I'm guessing the element is not found because it's added on document.ready and WebAii may begin looking for it prior to that event. Anyways, does anyone know how I can properly look for and find the desired element?  Thanks so much for any help or tips.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team and I were able to figure this out. Running the `waitForReady()` method against the current browser object allows the jQuery document.ready function to run and set up the page accordingly. The elements were easily located after this.